# How to get most frequent element on a string array in typescript

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I have the following object:

```
export namespace Data {
  export type AsObject = {
    a: string,
    b: string,
    c: string,
    d: number,
  }
}
```

And I need to find the most frequent string Data.AsObject.a from Data.AsObject[].
Can someone please share a code in typescript to do it ?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't explain what should happen in the case that the array is empty or that there is a tie for greatest occurrence, so I implemented it with these conditions:

- an empty array will throw an error
- a tie will result in only one being returned (the one which occurs first)

You'll need to modify it if you want to change the behavior of either of those.

> It's also implemented so that you can find the greatest occurrence of any other prop: just change the specified key as the second argument.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAREAXESDeBYAUEkhAB4wD2ATukugJ4zICCUA8gEYBWE8NAvDgJEiIAFxIo6SgEtgAcwDcQ4e3GSZ8pYWHw1U2YuVEAJuOABXMOwiUtRAL5b7BAgHpXSAJIAzWgAsbCAByKCQsdGkIABokcmAAGzpY4GRpUMoIdHNKFOMCb3NgXmk4pDkMjGh0Vnh4bIyi5AAeAGliEnQIYGNQgGsIOnJfNEwAOhYObl4APgAKZRBKSnERkHG2Lh50AG0AXSjlfrpxFoP8AEoVjDWJzd5tlt3BbXpGJAAVJAFV9cmth92diQ8DikiQYBAMC+SBSAHckABZSFNd4xCxWGxzc5aZTeKhIWYg4Bg8ixXyLSjnZ7CYGgmjSTpgaHkbZHQFGcGQ0ZQTKzBkQMAxWYQmCjOS8-lgKkAfmlSAADFSANRIACM2OUznwyiJYIyUHM8X4SG2ozNIt23Ko6Fms22MRA+xNMXYuypfGmSHYSAAtGFztt5btpaNA+ztNJfLNXhAhkh9Yb+HwBEFCsYIN5ZBBjEEqeg-JRyPC4UgAKJLKizIJMJYgJJpYhgGD0XNAjJZHLx6CJpwufDuAdIACqPKQ8Wk-X8aVEffcXiC8XiEl60ihmcXBli5ho+eQpCkWBghZgoVkU9PwBg2-a4Bg8QgM-wuvpjNCAm2ymwYiQQQCi-IQT2GcRBfuIv4QP+gHATg36-uQ8QgFBn6wbC0iLr05BgJAwBIdooE-uwcScOQ2S4SBsF+PBiFAchYGUQhuFPCAoQ-LcUw7OGBDPl2BpGtC5QQJUkg1HUSxdIgfKvjEQSIRqT6gvBECjPE5ByLMCZGtiSBzgARPRIA6QQQA)

```ts
namespace Data {
  export type AsObject = {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: string;
    d: number;
  };
}

// If there's a tie, only one is returned
function greatestOccurrence <K extends keyof Data.AsObject>(
  arr: Data.AsObject[],
  key: K,
): Data.AsObject[K] {
  type T = Data.AsObject[K];
  const map = new Map<T, number>();

  for (const o of arr) {
    const item = o[key];
    map.set(item, (map.get(item) ?? 0) + 1);
  }

  const result = [...map].sort(([, a], [, b]) => b - a)[0]?.[0];
  if (typeof result === 'undefined') throw new Error('Array is empty');
  return result;
}

///// Use like this:

// I'll skip filling out the extra props in this input example:
const items = [
  {a: 'hello'},
  {a: 'hello'},
  {a: 'hola'},
  {a: 'willkommen'},
  {a: 'bonjour'},
  {a: 'hola'},
  {a: 'hola'},
] as Data.AsObject[];

const result = greatestOccurrence(items, 'a');
console.log(result); // "hola"
```

Comment: Thanks a loooot!